# Sending an sms via server

Tags: android, ruby-on-rails, sms

I have been searching for a while now but couldn't get the answer I need

I am trying to build an android application, where the user will specify the number to send to and the body of SMS from my application, but I don't want to use Android SMSManager to handle the sending of the message. I need to have a server to handle the messaging but couldn't figure out how

So how can I implement a rails server to handle the messaging, where an android application is able to only send SMS through it

Comment: Send SMS body to server via REST API and use server to send the message to desired recipient.

Comment: But how can the server send the message to the desired recipient, charging user 1 (sending the message) carrier credit

Comment: Not sure of your use case here. But if you want to charge user for the sms you send from server you might want to maintain some kind of digital wallet, credits or currency. On your app startup query server to get it and allow user to send sms via your app only when sufficient credit is maintained.

Comment: sorry I wasn't clear about that, I only want to have the default carrier charge for sending the SMS, no any extra charge

Comment: Why do you not want to use Android SMSManager? If you want to send message through a server, you will need an SMS gateway.